# Send a var to FrontEnd without reloading Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i resend a var to frontend in node.js without reloading, redirecting or rendering again the page something like this.I created a chat and i don't want to reload the page after someone sent a message...Is a bot made with QnA Microsoft.

```
res.render('mainpage',{frontend_var:backend_var});
```

FrontEnd

```
<div class="direct-chat-messages">
            <%
            for(var i = 0; i < imax;i+=2){
            %>
            <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border">
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">You</span>
                </div>
                <div class="direct-chat-text ">
                    <%=message[i+1]%>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="direct-chat-msg  ">
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">BOT</span>
                </div>
                <img alt="message user image" src="http://www.pvhc.net/img27/awbgpcfkuwxixldjoown.png" class="direct-chat-img">
                <div class="direct-chat-text ">
                    <%=message[i]%>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%
            }
            %>
        </div>


    </div>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/users/send">
        <div class="popup-messages-footer">
            <input type="text" id="status_message" placeholder=" Type a message..." rows="10" cols="40" name="message">
            <span class="input-group-btn right"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" > <input type="submit" value="Send"></a></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

BackEnd

```
app.post('/send',upload.any(),function (req,res,next) {
    const translated = JSON.stringify({"question": req.body.message});
    const extServerOptionsPost = {
        host: 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
        path: 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases//generateAnswer',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(translated)
        }
    };

    const reqPost = http.request(extServerOptionsPost, function (bot) {
        bot.on('data', function (data) {
            process.stdout.write("done"); // primul console.log
            imax++;
            message[imax] = JSON.parse(data).answers[0].answer;
            imax++;
            message[imax] = req.body.message;
            res.render('Bot', {message:message , imax:imax});
        });
    });
    reqPost.write(translated);
});
```

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: Either way, the way to go in this case is to use JSON RPC

Comment: Check out socket io

Comment: Yes i use express

Comment: Alright, put in your frontend code, I'll write an answer real fast :)

Comment: @dGRAMOP can u provide a link or smth where i can read more about it and how to use it in my case?

Comment: You want either Ajax or WebSockets. Google them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your nodeJS: It will act as a backend hook that the frontend (far below) can keep contacting.

```
//Given chatObject is a variable you want to send to the client:
app.get("/updateChats", function(req,res)
{
 res.send(JSON.stringify(chatObject));
//Serializes the chatObject into a string
}
```

On the client side, you need to write some JSON sync stuff:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // if it worked, parse that string, make it back into an object
        var chatObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(chatObject)//do with it as you please :)
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/updateChats", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Consider `setInterval`'ing that sync code in the frontend to keep pulling/refreshing chat messages

Comment: Ok so someone has a vendetta against me and is downvoting all my answers. Please, if you have the nerve to downvote my answer, explain why. Or leave a message. :(

Comment: I did not XD, anyway i also have to receive a question from the user...Is a bot made with Qna Bot Microsoft, and i send a question then answer it...using this how should i work with this?Shall i put my backend code too?

Comment: Not your down-voter, but I'm consider down-voting this -- you state: "add this..." and show code, but you explain nothing in your answer. Why not make your answer useful for *everyone*, not just the OP, but explaining why you recommend what you recommend? Code comments are nice, but textual explanation is a whole lot better.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the feedback, I'll change my answer. To whoever has this vendetta against me: tell me where I messed up, and I'll fix it!

Comment: That sort of comment never works. if they down-vote enough of your answers, then this will trigger a reversal bot where the site corrects revenge down-votes. But again, this doesn't always work -- they need to DV enough to trigger the bot.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for that insight. Would you say I explained a  better in my question? I do agree, I kinda spat code and put in no explanation.

Comment: @dGRAMOP i posted my backend too, could you explain how your answer will work with what i have?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i do not have enough rep i'm a noobie sorry but i can't say it solved my problem since i do not know if this works with what i have and how should i put that's why i posted the backend now too!Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Alright, so let me just modify this for you and make it easier to consume hold on

Comment: @dGRAMOP i do now know how to thank you!You save my day buddy!

Comment: Actually, nevermind that, I'll need a lot more background on this. @GagiuFilip , I don't understand how that API works there

Comment: @dGRAMOP May i explain? From the frontend i have that chatbox...i write a question and i hit send...the question stirng goes to backend(that req.body.message) and i get the response as a Json. Then all i have to do is to send the data from that Json(that  message[imax] = JSON.parse(data).answers[0].answer;)...I save all this data in a unidimensional array(message) that i send to frontend with it's size(that imax)

Comment: So in this scenario, you'd just pass that message that you get back to the frontend. chatObj should become message[imax] or whatever, and set a decent polling interval with the XMLHttpRequest. You can find plenty of documentation on how to do that on w3schools, MDN etc

Comment: Yes but i would still have to hit that send button and that would still reload me the page, so i need something now that can transfer the message to backend without Post...And my problem get worst and worst

Comment: Well you woudn't hit send in this scenario, you'd have script that keeps checkin in the bacground